# Cast to a reflected Type in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, types, casting

Consider the following code:

```
object objFoo = MakeFoo(); // object MakeFoo(){return new Foo();}
MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(Program).GetMethod("Baz"); // Foo Baz(){return foo;}
Type typeFoo = methodInfo.ReturnType;
var result = (typeFoo)objFoo;
```

Do I need to do some magic with `typeFoo` to get the result?

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to do, after `Foo result`?

Comment: In the original code it is something like 
    MethodInfo methodInfo = ...
    typeFoo = methodInfo.ReturnType;
So I don't know which type it will be.

Comment: If you don't know what type it will be, how do you declare the variable on the left hand side?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

No :-)

**Case 1:**

```
object objFoo = MakeFoo(); // object MakeFoo(){return new Foo();}
Foo result = (Foo)objFoo;
```

There is no reflection here, because you know the `Foo` type at compile time.

**Case 2:** interfaces. Normally the best one... You don't know what exactly `MakeFoo` returns, but you know it's an `IFoo` interface...

```
object objFoo = MakeFoo(); // object MakeFoo(){return new Foo();}
IFoo result = (IFoo)objFoo;
```

**Case 3:** you aren't sure `MakeFoo` returns `Foo`

```
object objFoo = MakeFoo(); // object MakeFoo(){return new Foo();}

if (objFoo is Foo)
{
    Foo result = (Foo)objFoo;
}
```

or, similar

```
object objFoo = MakeFoo(); // object MakeFoo(){return new Foo();}

Foo foo = objFoo as Foo;

if (foo != null)
{
    // use foo
}
```

**Case 4:** type `Foo` is completely unknown to your program. You don't have a `Foo` class referenceable...

```
object objFoo = MakeFoo(); // object MakeFoo(){return new Foo();}
Type typeFoo = objFoo.GetType(); // You should check for null values before!

// and now?

dynamic foo = objFoo;

// because you know that foo can Quack(1, 2, 3)!
string result = foo.Quack(1, 2, 3); 

// note that it will explode with a RuntimeBinderException if there is no 
// string Quack(int, int, int) method!
```

the `dynamic` internally uses reflection. You could use reflection directly to get the `Quack` method and call it

**Case 5:** as case 4, but using directly reflection:

```
object objFoo = MakeFoo(); // object MakeFoo(){return new Foo();}
Type typeFoo = objFoo.GetType(); // You should check for null values before!
MethodInfo mi = type.GetMethod("Quack"); // You should check if the Quack method
                                         // exists
string result = (string)mi.Invoke(objFoo, new object[] { 1, 2, 3 });
```

or, with some sanity checks, if you aren't sure `foo` can `Quack` correctly:

```
MethodInfo mi = type.GetMethod("Quack", 
                    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, 
                    null, 
                    new[] { typeof(int), typeof(int), typeof(int) }, 
                    null);

if (mi != null && typeof(string).IsAssignableFrom(mi.ReturnType))
{
    string result = (string)mi.Invoke(objFoo, new object[] { 1, 2, 3 });
}
```

**Case -Infinity:**  type `Foo` is completely unknown to your program. You don't have a `Foo` class referenceable. You don't have an `IFoo` interface. You don't even know what a `Foo` is, you know only that it's a class (or perhaps it's a boxed `struct`, but it doesn't change from your point of view... It can't be an `interface` because in the end there must always be a concrete `class`/`struct` behind every `interface`). You don't know of its methods, its fields, its properties (because you don't know what `Foo` is).

Even if you can cast an `object` to this unknown class, what can you do? You can't have methods in your code that accept it as a parameter/return value, because if somewhere you had:

```
int INeedFoo(Foo par) { return 0; }
```

then clearly you would know of `Foo`. The .NET library can't have methods that accept it as a parameter/return value, because if it had, you would know of `Foo`.

The only thing you can do is pass it to some other methods that you discover through reflection that accept `Foo` as a parameter... But the `Invoke` method accepts an array of `object` as parameters... You don't need to cast your `object` to call `Invoke`! You only need to put it in the array.

Comment: I oversimplified the question :-)

Comment: @XyiTebe Tell me which of the three cases is the one you are interested in

Comment: Case with dynamic is the most relevant here, although it would be nice to know if I can cast to a type that is known at runtime.

Comment: @XyiTebe you can `Convert.ChangeType` to a type know at runtime, but for casting, you can (with tricks) but you wouldn't have a variable of the right type where to put the type. You can't have a `Foo myFoo` if you don't know of `Foo` when you are writing your code (barring some self-generating code possible through Expression trees and self-building code)... But in the end, even if you had a `Foo` variable you don't know anything of, what would you do? How could you know of the methods of a type you don't know? and all the reflection methods accept `object` for parameters and return `object`.

Comment: Yes, thank you. `dynamic` and `Convert.ChangeType` are two good ideas. 
You are right, dynamic probably is the best one, since declaration `Foo result` means that Foo is known at compile time and `obj result` will give object anyway. Seems a kind of limitation of a static-typed language.

Comment: @XyiTebe `Convert.ChangeType` is only really usefull to change from number types (so `int` to `long` or `int` to `float` or similar). The third way is `ToString()`... Sometimes what you really need is simply a `string` description :-) `Console.Write()` and many other methods simply use the `ToString()` to show the content of the parameters.

Comment: @xanatos - Oops :-0 ...here is a replacement...not sure where I copy/pasted the 2nd one from >> Just a note...when using Option 4 with the dynamic keyword in T4 templates you will need to add 2 assembly references <#@ Assembly Name="System.Core" #> and <#@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.CSharp" #>.

Answer (score 14):

This is the first result in google about Casting to a reflected type.

So for reference, in case sb wonders what would be a general way of casting to a reflected type:

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static T CastTo<T>(this object o) => (T)o;

    public static dynamic CastToReflected(this object o, Type type)
    {
        var methodInfo = typeof(ObjectExtensions).GetMethod(nameof(CastTo), BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        var genericArguments = new[] { type };
        var genericMethodInfo = methodInfo?.MakeGenericMethod(genericArguments);
        return genericMethodInfo?.Invoke(null, new[] { o });
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `ObjectExtensions` from? .NET Core 3 does not seem to have the class.

Comment: I dislike lack of clarity too, thanks for pointing it out. `ObjectExtensions` is an example static class these two methods are in. `CastToReflected` is useful for testing things or for hacky solutions, but be aware that it is rarely a good idea to use it in real worlds scenarios, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

This would be equivalent to:

```
object objFoo = MakeFoo();
Foo result = (Foo)objFoo;
```

There's no real point in casting an object to a type that's unknown at compile time - you won't be able to use it:

```
object objFoo = MakeFoo();
UnkownType result = (UknownType)objFoo;
```

Since you don't know what `UknownType` is, you won't be able to use any of its methods without resorting to reflection, or to dynamics.