# Create null instance from MethodInfo.ReturnType

Tags: c#, generics

Suppose I can successfully get the return type of a method:

```
var getResult = typeof(T).GetMethod("GetResult");
var ReturnType = getResult.ReturnType;
```

How can I then declare a null var of that return type? As in:

```
ReturnType somevar = null;
```

The reason I want this is because I have a loop afterwards (which is when 'somevar' gets populated with an instance). I later check the contents of 'somevar' outside the scope of the loop, which is why I can't declare the var in the loop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cast to a reflected Type in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18052562/cast-to-a-reflected-type-in-c-sharp) - To repeat (given `ReturnType` represents a type called `Foo`): "type `Foo` is completely unknown to your program. You don't have a `Foo` class referenceable. You don't have an `IFoo` interface. You don't even know what a `Foo` is [...] Even if you can cast an object to this unknown class, what can you do? You can't have methods in your code that accept it as a parameter/return value". --- In short: In order to cast to the type, the compiler needs to know it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing compile time with runtime. The problem is that getResult.ReturnType is a *value of type System.Type*.

When you use the 'var' statement compiler deduces the type of the variable 'ReturnType', it is therefore the same as

```
System.Type ReturnType = getResult.ReturnType;
```

You can't then use ReturnType in a declaration line for somevar, because the compiler doesn't see a runtime value for it.

What you should probably do is just do

```
object somevar = null;
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

`var returnType = getResult.ReturnType;` is equvalient to `Type returnType = getResult.ReturnType;`.

So, the `ReturnType` is of type `Type` that contains information about type that is returned from method `GetResult`.

If you want to create instance of that type, you can use `Activator`:

```
object somevar = Activator.CreateInstance(returnType); 
// assumig that return type of GetResult contains parameterless ctor
```

But still, you have to operate on `object` variable, thus return type is got by reflection.